# What is the use of multiple tables with 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: database

The following shows two tables, one has employee details and has their address. If both the tables has 'one to one' relationship (i.e one employee has only one address and vice versa), then why not combine the two into one table, like shown below.

- **Two tables with 1 to 1 relation**

[image]

- **Both tables combined into one.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of database analysis methods.
The first form is one that simplifies the schema in the case of the table used, employees and address it should merge.
The other method is called the third form, it consists in making the tables as independent as possible. In the case of the table employees and address it should be separated. There is no right or wrong method it is a choice to make.
However, if the database contains many tables, it is more sensible to simplify and get to the first form, but there is no obligation.

Comment: You can decide for yourself. If the data belongs together and a person always has only one address and an address always belongs to only one person, you could join the data in one table, but you're losing flexibility.
What if a single address belongs to two empoyees? What if...
The fact that I'm using two nouns (Person & Address) already suggests it's better to keep them separated.

Comment: If a single address belongs to two employees there will be a problem in the design and definition of the starting rules, because the relationship will be not "One to One" but "Many to One". Now we can just as well add a column address in the table Person nothing prevents it only there is a risk of redundancy of the data in the case where the address appears twice for two different persons.
It is for this reason that I say that we must leave it to the discretion of the person who conceives the care to decide what is best for each case.

Comment: @FoxCy But it is highly improbable to have two employees with the same address, unless they share the same room or live in the same house..so it is only natural that the relation can be 'one to one'. So in such a case as per you said it is only a personal choise to have two or one table. But having multiple table makes things tidy and more meaningful. Is that right?

Comment: If the database is large, the Address table should be justified. I know that during my exams when I had a one-to-one relationship, I had an interest in having a good reason to do so. If the company imposes it on the other hand we have no choice, but if we have the choice, I think it is better to collect the two tables by adding a column. Moreover, when you have to display results, it avoids having a join to do.

Comment: @Arjob Mukherjee Yes but you can have a primary key with the number of the employee in the table employees and a secondary key with the same number of the employee in the table adress to link properly each adress with each employee.

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is a quality decision while de-normalization is a performance decision.

---

If you would join the two tables, and store them as one, your reads and writes would be faster because you will not have to go through the query to join these two tables to work with their combined data.

However, if you keep the tables separate, then looking at individual tables' data may make more sense to you and also give you the freedom to modify one table's data without touching other's. But to work with the joined data of the two tables in 1 to 1 relation would force you to write a (maybe unnecessary) join query every time.

---

The decision is yours to make in the end. IMO, unless the performance of separated tables is below acceptance, leaving the data stored in a cleaner manner may be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have a 1-1 relationship then you have a mutual functional dependency so you get no normalisation benefit.

However there may be reasons to do this:

1. Easier management of difference in permission.
2. Easier management of null values
3. faster aggregation within the table
4. Avoid running heavy triggers on unnecessary frequent updates

On the other hand aggregation across the join becomes more expensive.